# How To Save ArrayList of Object to CSV/XLS file

Tags: java, excel, arraylist, export, apache-poi

I'm struggling weeks with the export of the arraylist to a CSV/XLS file. How can I do it? Maybe using POI API? But I really don't know where I could start...

Can anyone help me? Thank you so much ;-)

Table class:

```
public abstract class TestTable extends JFrame   {
protected static FileData FileData = new FileData();
public static void main(String args[]) {

{
    JFrame meinFrame = new JFrame("Beispiel JFrame");
    JTable fileTable = new JTable(TestTable.FileData);
    JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(fileTable);
    meinFrame.getContentPane().add(scrollPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    meinFrame.setSize(500, 500);
    meinFrame.setVisible(true);
}
}
}
```

Code of the arraylist:

```
public class FileData extends AbstractTableModel implements FilenameFilter {
List<Object[]> data = new ArrayList<>();
String titles[] = new String[] { "File Name", "Path" };
Class<?> types[] = new Class[] { String.class, String.class };
public FileData() {
this("C:\\");
}
public FileData(String directory) {
File inputFiles = new File(directory);
setFileStats1(inputFiles);
}
public int getRowCount() {
return this.data.size();
}
public int getColumnCount() {
return this.titles.length;
}
public String getColumnName(int column) {
return this.titles[column];
}
public Class<?> getColumnClass(int column) {
return this.types[column];
}
public Object getValueAt(int row, int column) {
return this.data.get(row)[column];
}
public void setFileStats1(final File directory) {
this.data = new ArrayList<>();
    for (File file : directory.listFiles()) {

            this.data.add(new Object[] { file.getName(), file.getAbsolutePath() });
    }
}
public boolean accept(File directory, String name) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
return false;
}
}
```

Comment: You can use [JasperReports](http://community.jaspersoft.com/project/jasperreports-library). Its a very diverse library for excel and pdf export with Collection / ResultSet / Hibernate Query Results as data source. Underneath it uses apache POI library and provide many additional features.

Comment: Here a code that does same thing in C#. It may give you a clue to tackle your problem. http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/9c412fb2-a352-43b2-9443-e699aa1ed28e/how-to-save-arraylist-of-object-class-to-csv-file

Comment: thanks! @ares I prefer to use another method.